# Why localhost:19530 shows 404 page not found for Milvus connection

Tags: python, docker, vector-database, milvus

I'm trying to build a Milvus database by Docker and I follow the steps of this link: https://milvus.io/docs/install_standalone-docker.md to make connection. However, when I look up localhost:19530 on Chrome, it always shows a "404 page is not found". is that normal or did I miss some steps

Answer (score 0):

The 19530 is the grpc service port for milvus. And gprc is HTTP based protocol, but you cannot get an index page on it like a web service does, you should use a milvus client such as pymilvus to connect it for use Milvus.